# How to skip a specific parametrized test?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a parametrized Pytest test such as:

```
testdata = [
    MyDB(id="0001", result=True),
    MyDB(id="0002", result=False)
]
@pytest.mark.parametrize("data", testdata, ids=[repr(id) for id in testdata])
def test_1(data):
    pass
```

The question is, how can I use @pytest.mark.skipif to skip the test with id "0001"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [pytest.param](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#set-marks-or-test-id-for-individual-parametrized-test) ([reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-param)) which accepts a `marks` optional argument:

```py
testdata = [
    pytest.param(MyDB(id="0001", result=True), marks=pytest.mark.skip)
    MyDB(id="0002", result=False)
]
@pytest.mark.parametrize("data", testdata, ids=[repr(id) for id in testdata])
def test_1(data):
    pass
```

You also can (and it is a good practice) indicate why the test is skipped:

```py
pytest.param(MyDB(id="0001", result=True),
              marks=pytest.mark.skip(reason=('a good and informative reason'))
```